# Shall I switch from Express.JS to Sails.JS?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, chatbot

I've got a chatbot module developed on Node.JS (Express.JS) so things are really getting messy as it's a SaaS, however I was wondering if Express.JS is maybe not the right technological choice here?
Can you advise? Thanks!

Comment: Things getting messy is a problem that has nothing to do with the framework you are using .. with any framework you can get into the same situation if you are not refactoring and cleaning your code from time to time. I think, you just need to refactor your module, adopt a good and understandable folder structure (the one used in sails/laraval/rails for example).

Comment: I'm actually stuck at refactoring , there is a lot to be done and I don't find the design patterns that are regular in java and dotNet very straightforwad or easy to implement in expressjs , besides ,even when I'm manually emplementing what I want , which is taking a lot of time, I feel that there is out there somebody whom work must be similar and that there is definitely a solution out there..

Comment: In my case, sails.js failed miserably when things got complicated. If you want to switch express with something, I strongly recommend you to give https://adonisjs.com a try